# ns2 DSR modifications

Tags: header, ns2

I am working on enhancing the DSR implementation of NS2. I have added some extra fields to the DSR header (in class hdr_sr in hdr_sr.h). I need to fill these additional fields at the time of dsr header construction. I am unable to figure out exactly which function I need to modify. My understanding is that this happens in 'sendOutPacketWithRoute' in dsragent.cc.